# How does puma master process transfer the request to workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, operating-system, puma

I've been searching for an answer on this but I couldn't find one.

How does Puma master process communicates with the workers ? How the master process sends the request to the worker ? Is this done with shared memory ? Unix socket ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The master doesn't deal with requests, it merely monitors the workers and restarts them when necessary.

The workers, independently, will *pull* requests from some queueing system, e.g. a TCP port or unix socket.